# Why does android emulator restore after installing an apk file?

Tags: android, android-emulator

After I installed an apk with the command: "adb install something.apk", I closed emulator and opened it again. I didn't see my app "something" anymore. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have wiped the user data from your emulator.

---

Make sure you uncheck "Wipe user data" when your start the emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you start the emulator from the command line, make sure you don't use the `-wipe-data` option. If you use the AVD Manager, uncheck the "Wipe user data" checkbox.